# How to set xmlns path in PreferenceScreen - modified ListPreferenceMultiSelect

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I have the code downloaded from site: http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240

But on the line:

```
<com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect
```

Is error code:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'checkAll' in package 
     'com.threefiftynice.android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'separator' in package 
     'com.threefiftynice.android'
```

This is XML with error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:key="prefKey"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.threefiftynice.android">  
    <com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect 
        threefiftyprefs:checkAll="check" threefiftyprefs:separator="|"
        android:defaultValue="#ALL#"
        android:key="key"
        android:title="Image folders to monitor" android:dialogTitle="Image folders to monitor"
        android:summary="Specify which folders should be monitored for images"
        android:entries="@array/typeOfPoints"
        android:entryValues="@array/typeOfPointsID"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I know xmlns and the path to ListPreferenceMultiselect ist bad - but I tried a lot of possible paths and problem was with all of them (this is the original path from the site with original packages). This is my structure of the code

: 
[image]

How should I set the path to make it work? Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**
After chanded it to `xmlns:threefiftyprefs="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` it does not write error in xml but it throws error on run:

> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{goandknow.proximityalerts/goandknow.proximityalerts.EditPreferences}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)      at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect       at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493) 
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>     at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:250)
>     at
>   android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:253)
>     at
>   goandknow.proximityalerts.EditPreferences.onCreate(EditPreferences.java:24)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
>     ... 11 more

This is line 24:

> com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect

Comment: Try changing the line xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.threefiftynice.android" to xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Thank you very much it helped - but now it throw error when I try to run it in code. I posted the logcat output - You don't know what could be wrong - `com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect`  this is OK?

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: That didn't help. Error is not visible in eclipse - it crush when I try to show preferences. Isn't problem with `com.threefiftynice.android.preference.ListPreferenceMultiSelect` ? I don't have this structure in project (com.threefiftynice. ...)

Comment: In which package your ListPreferenceMultiSelect java file is?

Comment: Thanks, now it's working :) I had to change it to `goandknow.models.ListPreferenceMultiSelect`. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line

`xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.threefiftynice.android"`

to

`xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:key="prefKey"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:threefiftyprefs="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">  
    <goandknow.models.ListPreferenceMultiSelect 
    threefiftyprefs:checkAll="check" threefiftyprefs:separator="|"
    android:defaultValue="#ALL#"
    android:key="key"
    android:title="Image folders to monitor" android:dialogTitle="Image folders"
    android:summary="Specify which folders should be monitored for images"
    android:entries="@array/typeOfPoints"
    android:entryValues="@array/typeOfPointsID"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Important:

**xmlns:threefiftyprefs="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
goandknow.models.ListPreferenceMultiSelect** Thanks to Sankar V.